# How to store return value from function with argument in a variable?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal

I'm struggling with storing the return value (0 or 1) of my function in a variable. Whatever I try, $var ends up being empty or I run into error messages.
Here is my specific code:

```
function screen_exists() {
        if screen -list | grep -q "${1}"; then
          return 0
        else
          return 1
        fi
    }

VAR=$(screen_exists "${PLAYER_SCREEN_NAME}")
echo ${VAR}
```

I've also tried with a super simple function that always returns 0, but same outcome.

Comment: @Cyrus That was a copy&paste error on my part. I'm sorry, fixed it!

Comment: Your function can just be `screen_exists () { screen -list | grep -q "$1"; }`. The return code of the function will be `0` (success) if `grep` finds a match. You should follow this convention, rather than returning `1` for success and `0` for failure. It will allow you to use the function like `if screen_exists "name"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(...)` is command substitution syntax that is used to capture output of given command. If you want to store return value of a function then use `$?`:

```
screen_exists() {
    screen -list | grep -q "$1"
    # implicit here is: return $?
}

screen_exists "${PLAYER_SCREEN_NAME}"
ret=$?
```

Also note that this function will return `1` if `grep` doesn't find search patter and `0` if it is success which is the standard norm in shell utilities.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know `$?` was a thing. All my google searches suggested something like `ret=$(function)` and I tried to tweak that according to my needs.

Comment: Thanks @TomFenech, both valid points. I have added them in my answer.